# Нужно ли тире и кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире и кавычки?

`1. «Нехорошо» – значит «плохо».`

`2. «Хорошо» – не значит «отлично».`

Comment: Тире нужно, а по поводу кавычек не знаю.